# Transfer data from Entity to DTO with Nestjs

Tags: typescript, nestjs

I need to get `user` detail infomation. After query, I get an `User Entity`:

```
export class User{
    name: string;
    username:string;
    password:string;
    salt:string;
}
```

But I don't want to return `user password` so I create an `DTO`:

```
export class GetUserDto{
    name: string;
    username:string;
}
```

So what is the best way to transfer data from `Entity` to `Dto` without unwanted field.

Comment: I want to find an advance way in the `nestjs` framework instead of javascript built in

Comment: use validation pipe in nestjs with `whitelist` set to true. you can read more about it https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/validation

Comment: you could use this lib as well: https://automapperts.netlify.app

Answer (score 0):

You can use serialization, see this => https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/serialization

Example :

```js
import { Exclude } from 'class-transformer';

export class User {
  public name: string;
  public username:string;
  public salt:string;

  @Exclude()
  public password: string;

  constructor(partial: Partial<UserEntity>) {
    Object.assign(this, partial);
  }
}
```